# Azure Windows Docker Container Instance Gives 404 Not Found

Tags: azure, docker, containers

I'm using Docker Windows Container and from Visual Studio, I can hit F5 and have a simple "Hello World" controller run. I hit `/api/helloworld`, everything works fine and dandy - I see Hello World.

Now when I deploy this on Azure Container Instance everything looks like it deployed fine. But when I hit the same url `/api/helloworld` it gives me a 404 message.

Do I need to grant any read permissions for anonymous web users?

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'win1803'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockermicroservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dockermicroservice
    build:
      context: .\DockerMicroservice
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

**HelloWorldController.cs**

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DockerMicroservice.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

**Run instance from container registry**

[image: Run instance from container registry]

Comment: You can take a look at the ACI logs. And I do not see you expose the port in the Dockerfile. Maybe it's the problem.

Comment: Any update? did the above recommendation help?

Comment: I added the port, but that didn't solve the issue. Not sure how to set up the logs so I can see where it is falling down.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my issue.

I was missing doing a publish before building my image.

- Right click the project > **Publish**
- Choose **folder** for the publishing target
- type in **obj\docker\publish** (or whatever it says in your COPY step in the Dockerfile)

Comment: After publishing this through the folder can you also publish it again through visual studio to a container registry?